# Where is <regex> in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I am back-porting a VS2010 project to VS2005 (don't ask why..).  In VS2010 the following works just fine:

```
#include <regex>
```

But in VS2005 its a fatal error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'regex': No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I should add that I am a C++ / VS newbie.  If  is simply not part of VS2005, I also welcome suggestions on what to use as a regex library.

Thanks!

Comment: <regex> is part of C++0x - why do you think an old C++ compiler should have it?

Comment: Actually it comes from TR1, so it's not impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `<regex>` in VS2005. That header is part of the new C++ standard features which are partially supprted by VS2010, but not supported at all by VS2005.

However, `<regex>` is based on [boost.regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html), which can be downloaded for Windows at [boostpro.com](http://www.boostpro.com/download/)

Comment: Thank you.  Is there an easy way to just get boost/regex.hpp out of boost so I don't have to checkin this entire library?

Comment: @NPike The boostpro installer offers the choice to install only select parts of boost.

Comment: Or use boost's bcp tool - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/tools/bcp/bcp.html

Answer (score 0):

The header  (from TR1) has been added in Visual Studio 2008. See the [Visual C++ 2008 Feature Pack Release from MDSN](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=D466226B-8DAB-445F-A7B4-448B326C48E7&displaylang=en), search for regex:

> TR1 Known Issues:
>
> TR1 consists of new headers (e.g. regex) and additions to existing headers (e.g. memory).